# Archive for custom fields?

Tags: custom-field, archives, template-hierarchy

Recently I've done a nice taxonomy system on my WordPress website. Created also the taxonomy archive template files, so wherever I'm listing the taxonomies I can click on them and will bring me on a results page filtered by the clicked taxonomy.

I'm wondering if the same situation can be reproduced also with custom fields? I know custom fields are different by hierarchical tackle, but just wondering.

Comment: What is "hierarchical tackle"? What situation do you want to reproduce, exactly?

Comment: Custom fields has different hierarchy than taxonomies. I would like to click on a custom field value (word) and to bring me on a page with results filtered by that custom field, kind an archive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress does not support by default `custom_field`s archive like for taxonomies (*yeah, taxonomies can have categories*) but we can create a destination page with page template (*linked from the listed `custom_field`*) and added a searching on the `custom_field`, like this (*from the **listing page***):

```
<?php
if (get_post_meta($post->ID,'_my_meta',TRUE)) :
    $key_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_my_meta',TRUE);
endif;
?>
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/?s=<?php echo $key_meta[meta_field]; ?>"><?php echo $key_meta[meta_field]; ?></a>
```

The destination page's layout we can customize by preferences.